# how can you access locahost subdomain on iphone/ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, proxy, localhost

Has anyone configured a mobile dev setup where ios browser debugging would resolve to the localhost URL in the host machine?

I keep finding articles of people using tunnels to route their traffic from localhost to a random web address or their IP address and debug on their ios browser.

`subdomain.123.0.0.1:PORT`

It works, but not for my current setup due to some backend design and legacy code, I cannot change this. Also, I cannot jailbreak the iphone just to change the hosts file

What I need is to specifically resolve my browser URL on my mobile device to `subdmain.localhost:PORT` just like one would request it on desktop. Any help is very welcome

*sidenote: I already figured this out on android and it was super easy. I can't believe this is not the case for iphone/ipad*

Comment: Have you tried charles proxy?  What do you mean "localhost in the host machine"?  What is the host machine?  Your PC running some debugger? There is comprehensive debugging available for Safari on IOS using Safari on an attached Mac

Comment: Also, 123.0.0.1 isn't localhost; 127.0.0.1 is localhost, and 127.0.0.1 on the iOS device *is the iOS device*.  If you want to access some other device you would need to specify the IP address of that PC, but you can't specify `subdomain.ipaddress` because IP addresses are not DNS names

Comment: What I wrote was just pseudo code, I am aware that localhost is 127.0.0.1. The host machine is the machine that hosts the running server. I'm trying to access that server from my mobile phone by typing `subdomain.localhost`, I used charles but the network proxy only works for one port

Comment: But localhost in this case is the mobile phone?  If you want the phone to access your PC then you need to use your Pc's IP address or a DNS name that resolves to that address.

Comment: @Paulw11 what would be a good DNS solution?